# React Native Component not updating with state changes

Tags: reactjs, fetch, react-native

So I have done a lot of React web development.  Not a lot of React Native but this is really crazy to me.  I have this component

relevant code

```
 componentDidMount() 

    axios.get(URL + 'ATL')
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log("AXRES1::",response);
        this.setState({
          rows: response.data,
          loading: false,
        })
    }.bind(this))
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log("AXRES2::",error.message);
       this.setState({ loading: false })
    }.bind(this))
    .finally(function () {
      console.log("AXRES3::");
      this.setState({ loading: false })
    }.bind(this));

  }

render() {
    const placeholder = {
      label: 'Select SSA Region...',
      value: this.state.region,
      color: '#093387',
    };
    console.log("ROWS::",this.state.rows.length)
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Swiper
            from={1}
            minDistanceForAction={0.1}
            controlsProps={{
              dotsTouchable: true,
              prevPos: 'bottom-left',
              nextPos: 'bottom-right',
              nextTitle: '',
              prevTitle: '',
              nextTitleStyle: { color: '#2298f2', fontSize: 50, fontWeight: '500' },
              prevTitleStyle: { color: '#2298f2', fontSize: 50, fontWeight: '500' }
            }}
          >
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Title style={styles.header}><Text h1>SSA Regional Locator App</Text></Title>
              <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Image
                  style={{}}
                  source={Images.USM}
                />
              </View>
            </View>

            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <Title style={styles.header}>Choose a Region</Title>
              <Title style={styles.header}>Find an Office {this.state.rows.length}</Title>
              <RNPickerSelect
                placeholder={placeholder}
                items={regions}
                onValueChange={value => {
                  console.log("VALUE::",value);
                  this.setState({
                    region: value,
                  });
                }}
                style={pickerSelectStyles}
                value={this.state.region}
                useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
              />
              <DataTable>
                <DataTable.Header style={headerStyles}>
                  <DataTable.Title><Subheading>RO Name</Subheading></DataTable.Title>
                  <DataTable.Title><Subheading>Email</Subheading></DataTable.Title>
                  <DataTable.Title numeric><Subheading>Business Line</Subheading></DataTable.Title>
                  <DataTable.Title numeric><Subheading>State</Subheading></DataTable.Title>
                </DataTable.Header>
                {this.state.rows.map((row, i) => {
                  const img = "../images/flags/" + row.stateCode + ".png"
                  // console.log("ROW2::", img);
                  return (
                    <DataTable.Row key={i} style={rowStyles}>
                      <DataTable.Cell style={rowStyles}>{row.name}</DataTable.Cell>
                      <DataTable.Cell style={rowStyles}>{row.email}</DataTable.Cell>
                      <DataTable.Cell style={rowStyles} numeric>{row.businessLine}</DataTable.Cell>
                      <DataTable.Cell style={rowStyles} numeric>
                        <Image
                          style={{ width: 16, height: 12 }}
                          source={Images.flags[row.stateCode]}
                        />
                      </DataTable.Cell>
                    </DataTable.Row>
                  )
                })}
                <DataTable.Pagination
                  page={1}
                  numberOfPages={3}
                  onPageChange={(page) => { console.log(page); }}
                  label="1-2 of 6"
                />
              </DataTable>
            </View>
          </Swiper>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

I am updating my rows successfully.  I can view my console logs which indicate a change in values from 1 to 652 rows from the console log statement between my render and return.

```
2019-09-13 15:54:10.109 2708-2976/com.regionlocator I/ReactNativeJS: 'ROWS::', 1

2019-09-13 15:54:12.613 2708-2976/com.regionlocator I/ReactNativeJS: 'ROWS::', 652
```

The data also looks correct from my fetch which I check here

```
console.log("AXRES1::",response)
```

It's the array of objects I'm expecting.  But my datatable never changes.  No errors either.   What am I missing.  I'm very perplexed.

****One more important note

I should have mentioned when i originally posted, if I uncomment `console.log("ROW2::", img);` I see those console logs which reflect the new data from my fetch. I find it really strange this isn't rendering in android emulator new datatable items since clearly the items are being mapped.  Is there something special about rendering in react native and emulators maybe I'm not aware of.  This would certianly be showing up in React Web app I feel.

Comment: Indeed, your parent component is rerendering because you see the 'ROWS::' logs, but is the DataTable child actually rerendering?
You have a "console.log("ROW2::", img);" statement in comment; do you actually see these being logged when state changes? It is possible that the DataTable, similar to a FlatLlist, does not trigger a rerender in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned when i uncomment ```console.log("ROW2::", img);``` I see those console logs wihich reflect the new data from my fetch.  I find it really strange this isn't rendering in emulator since clearly I am getting console logs the code is running seems it should be rendering.

Comment: This is a perfect example why using the array index as the react key doesn't work, the object updated but the key remains the same so react bails on re-rendering. Try using a key unique to the element, like `key={row.email}` or `key={row.name}`, whatever can provide new unique keys between data updates.

Comment: I was using the index because I can't gaurantee another unique value in the array.  That said I tried this ```<DataTable.Row key={generateKey(row.name)} style={rowStyles}>``` where generateKey is using DateTime getTime and still it does not render the table in with rows in the emulator.

Comment: I see you have the DataTable.Pagination from the example still in your code. Did you try to remove it?
Also it's probably best to downsize your code and start with a minimal example. Something like on https://snack.expo.io/S1otnpjIr, which uses the component's state to update the table rows.
Your stylesheets could be relevant as well, especially the rowStyles. It is best to add this to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the [Swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) component and it worked.   I did see some other posts with setState issues within the [Swiper](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper) component.  Maybe with how I was using it, not sure.   This was just a proof of something so I tried to put everything together real quick.   Either way just thought I would post if anyone comes back here.